# Is a combinational logic circuit a Finite State Machine?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, state-machines

Is a combinational logic circuit a Finite State Machine?

In other words, is the class of combinational circuits a subset of the class of Finite state machines?

Comment: Combinational logic has no state. As such you can pretend it has one state (perhaps called "I exist") which can only be entered by powering up the machine and only left by powering down or destroying it, but I question the usefulness of that.

Comment: @user_1818839 the usefulness of this is performing combinational logic using FSM, and FSM using ROM. The updated answer by user Eugene Sh is useful

Comment: I think you answered your own question: combinational logic is "stateless" but an FSM will "have memory and state". Something that is stateless can not "have...state", and something that has state can not be "stateless". The output of combinational logic never depends on its previous state, only on its present input values.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson if you really are refuting the accepted answer, why don't you go ahead and write your own answer?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Of course it has a state. The output is a state. There is no need to have a memory to have a state. The memory is only required to make decisions based on previous states, but it is not a necessary attribute of a general FSM

Comment: You already knew what answer you wanted when you wrote the question (in fact you answered your own question at the same time you asked it), so there's no point in someone trying to change your mind. I think this is an inconsequential question about semantics, so go ahead and believe as you want.

Comment: @EugeneSh, Deleted my comment. I thought I was responding to the OP.

Comment: FWIW the question was edited making it less specific. The initial question asked whether the combinatorial logic can be seen as a subset of FSM.

Comment: I answered the question I saw: "Combinational logic is a stateless computational model. This is in contrast to Finite State Machines (FSM) which have memory and state. Is combinational logic a Finite State Machine?"

Comment: Anyway, not directly related to the question, but there is a well defined hierarchy of computational models:  ("stateless" systems) ⊂ (Finite Automata) ⊂ (Pushdown Automata) ⊂ (Turing Machines)

Comment: @ElliotAlderson of course you are free to think as you please. I think there is more to this question than what meets the eye.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson may I know why did you roll back my edit? I edited it to make the question clearer.

Comment: Why do you keep changing the question to fit the answer you have already accepted? That seems inconsiderate of those who have commented on your original question or tried to answer it.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson "subset", "is-a" and "is a" are terms that have more or less the same meaning. The difference is "is-a" is a more formal term that is well defined in computer science. I request you to please let me add this to my question. My original question was "Is combinational logic a subset of the Finite State Machine?"

Comment: @ShashankVM - Hi, Your self-answered question has already received other answers to a previous version. The question cannot now be changed (yet again). Please see the "chameleon question" problem discussed on Meta.SE and please do not attempt to change this question again. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson I want to edit the question to add clarity because it has been closed due to "lack details or clarity". Please help to reopen the question or edit it so it can be reopened. It does not look like a site that supports learning if questions are closed by people just because of disagreement.

Comment: @ShashankVM - "*You can't simply close a question*" I did not close the question, I just put it back in the same state as it was, before your edit. It has been closed *twice* by community voting. If you want to make a case for the question being edited or reopened, then please ask on [meta] & get community feedback - because as you see from the other answers, they were having to do extra work when you changed the question, and that is generally not acceptable. || I look forward to seeing your question on meta. If there is general agreement that the question can be changed, it'll be reopened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer is answering the original question, that was edited later: "Is combinatorial logic can be seen as a subset of FSM".

Combinatorial circuit is a Finite State Machine. In Mealy representation it will be an FSM with a single state and self-transition on any input with outputs depending solely on the inputs. For example an AND gate can be represented as the following FSM:

[image]

(Note about notation - the triangle is indicating the FSM "initial state".)

In Moore representation it will have the number of states corresponding to the number of possible outputs. For AND it will look like this:

[image]

In the above notation, the square is indicating output in this state. The initial state can be any of these.

Comment: Downvoters, this answer is giving a *formal* justification/proof. Please provide *formal* refutation instead of anonymous downvoting or handwaving.

Comment: I just saw your  comment on the OPs question to the effect that the question used to ask something different. I agree that this is a good answer to what the OP originally asked. I regret my downvote.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thank you for acknowledging :) Let me add a not which question it is answering to.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, though I imagine you are one of mine. But @SolomonSlow beat me to writing "proving a screw is actually a type of nail" will not be of any use across industry to build, test or support anything. Please give justification/proof of five examples of stateless digital logic FSMs (or whatever you want to call it) that actually got made in those billions in phones, PCs, kettles, tea machines, nuclear control systems etc that surround us and that make this website possible. Without redefining normal circuits as FSMs. My answer emphasises on actual digital logic and engineering.

Comment: @TonyM Yes, I did downvote your answer and I explained why. The question is not asking about circuits, engineering, or real-world applications or engineering jargon. It is asking about formalism of computational models. The answer is given in that context.

Comment: I agree that my edit it might have created some confusion, so I have edited it once more and remove the unnecessary parts of the question.

Answer (score 1):

**The OP has changed their actual question five times. This was written while the question was:**

- "Combinational logic is a stateless computational model. This is in contrast to Finite State Machines (FSM) which have memory and state. Is combinational logic a Finite State Machine?"

No, a combinatorial digital logic circuit is not a digital logic state machine, by any definition.

A combinatorial digital logic circuit contains no memory elements and responds immediately to changes in its inputs to produce its outputs. Each combination of inputs produces a fixed output combination.

A Finite State Machine (FSM)* contains combinatorial logic and also state memory. It produces outputs O and a new state N that are a logic function of its current state S and its inputs I.

Each combination of FSM inputs does not produce a fixed output combination. The outputs depend upon the state and the state depends on what the inputs have previously done. The state is stored in the memory circuit and gives the FSM the functions of sequence and elapsed time that the combinatorial logic does not have.

An FSM machine that was indistinguishable from a combinatorial logic circuit by the behaviour of its inputs and consequent outputs would not contain any state activity and therefore need no state memory. Therefore a combinatorial logic circuit would be used.

Note that the combinatorial circuit outputs are outputs - they are not a 'state'. No more than the output of an oscillator is an output waveform, not its state.

The term 'state' does mean other things in wider electronics. The digital logic term 'state' could be hijacked away from its satisfactory use in FSMs to mean 'output'. But you will find little example of this in the vast array of digital electronics components, programmable logic components, circuitry and support software tools on the market. So it is of no practical value to do so and could only produce confusion if done.

Note that this answer confines itself to practical electronics design engineering. There is a whole wider science of theory and analysis on FSMs themselves and for other applications. Beyond that, you might bump into some less scientific and frankly whimsical notions of the circuits or terms described. They can also argue that 1=2 but to no useful end in electronics engineering.

**I could go into Mealy and Moore FSMs, where the output is a function of I and S or just of S, but they are (a) already written up well on the internet and (b) not the goal of the question.*

Comment: FSM is a formal construct having a strict mathematical definition, which you can find in the link below. A combinatorial circuit which can be viewed as single state machine is strictly satisfying this definition. I can easily write a formal quintuple for the FSM whose diagram I gave in my answer above. Therefore your claim "No, a combinatorial digital logic circuit is not a digital logic state machine, by any definition." is clearly false. Of course, you can call it  "whimsical notions", but FSM is first of all an abstraction and is driven by strict formalism.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Mathematical_model

Comment: "Note that this answer grounded in practical electronics design engineering, not any whimsical notions of the circuits or terms described" Seriously? Are you trying to dismiss someone else whom you know nothing about? It generally isn't a good idea to make blanket statements such as these.

Comment: @ShashankVM, *"seriously? dismiss"* Since I don't refer to anything or anyone specifically, who am I "seriously?" dismissing exactly? I simply stated what was included by my answer: that this answer relates to the actual circuits you find in the world, not the ones you won't find. To be honest, it reads like you've made a blanket interpretation of what I 'really' mean. I think it's a clear answer. Meanwhile, you have totally rewritten your question rather than composing it carefully before asking it. It has a lot of downvotes and VTCs by other people.

Comment: @TonyM it is obvious that you won't have to write "note that this answer..." unless you are criticizing another answer. People can read your answer and judge for themselves if your answer is indeed grounded in engineering or not. There really is no need in making tall claims to sound like an authority in the field.

Comment: @ShashankVM, oh, I *see*. *"it is obvious"* No, it isn't. Please just go on what it is written. That's a serious presumption of your part. Why not first comment "can I ask who/what your are referring to..." to be sure of your facts, instead of straight to harsh accusations and downvote? I have made it extra-clear for you. Please do not modify your question to suit what you later realise. Please  act in accordance with https://electronics.stackexchange.com/conduct to make sure of your facts and assume the best of others before commenting.

Comment: @TonyM one can refute what a question states, because a question *can* contain incorrect facts. In your answer, you can very well write "No, a FSM does not need to have memory". Is it mentioned anywhere that an FSM has memory? Just because the question states that FSM has memory, that does not justify stating FSM has memory in your answer.

Comment: @ShashankVM, I really don't know what you’re talking about, or what you have been, but it's clearly not in the interests of the site, its users, its goals, its standards or the standards of professional engineering. This is not Fb. The question is unanswerable because you kept changing it. The answer is clear and unambiguous. You seem to have targeted me personally. Please stop.